# Angular component interaction between same component of different instances

Tags: angular

What is the best way to implement this requirement ?
I have a page with 2 selection lists, when I select an item in the selection list that selection should be disabled in the other selection list

The selection list is an angular component and it takes as input the selected item so I have that information in the component
when I change the selection in the component I of course get the selection to the component but how do I interact with the other instance of the component

-Jani

Comment: Well, there are multiple ways to do it. One is to expose a property that indicates the component is selected. And you can use `ViewChildren` to hold the list of the components and then if you want to find the selected one check the property.

Comment: What about holding the selected items in a service,

Update the service each time you select an item

In this way, If one instance have item selected, you will know that in the second instance

Answer (score 2):

If the lists are both within the same parent, you should be able to achieve this using the `@Ouput` property in the first list (where you select the item) and pass that through the parent to the second component using its `Input` property.

Something among the following lines:

**list.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  template: `
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let i of items" (click)="change(i)" [ngClass]="{active: isActive(i)}">{{ i }} </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styles: ['li{font-family:Calibri,Verdana}','li.active{color:red}']
})
export class ListComponent  {
  @Input() item: string
  @Output() changeCurrent = new EventEmitter<string>();

 items:string[] = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4']

  change(el:string):void {
    this.changeCurrent.emit(el)
  }

  isActive(el:string):boolean {
    return this.item == el
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>List 1</h1>
<app-list (changeCurrent)="change($event)"></app-list>


<h1>List 2</h1>
<app-list [item]=currentEl></app-list>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  currentEl:string = 'item4'

  change(el:string) {
    console.log(el)
    this.currentEl = el
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, there is one slight misconception in this example : Items should be component not the container list.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a Service that contains the source of the data (either a simple object or an Observable/Subject).

Then any number of components can just query the Service to get the single source of data.

Answer (score 0):

Jani, I understand that you has a "parent" component and your childrens component has an`@Input` teh list. As you pass as `@Input` and "object" (well, an Array) each change on the array will be see for the two components. If your list is an array of object

```
list=[{value:'one',selected:0},{value:'two',selected:0},...]
```

Your component list can be has an adiccional parameter ìndex, so your component is

```
<app-list [list]="list" [index]="1">
<app-list [list]="list" [index]="2">
```

You component list can be like

```
@Input() list
@Input() index

<div *ngFor="let item of list">
   <button [disabled]="item.selected!=0 && item.selected!=index"
           (click)="item.selected=item.selected==index?0:index">
        {{item.value}}
   </button>
</div>
```

Then you has in your component the list with select=1 the selected in the first app-list, and with selected=2 in the second one